# How to use ansible blockinfile on multiple files?

Tags: ansible

hi I would like to use the blockinfile function on multiple files going to change blocks of text in each of them.

unfortunately blockinfile does not support this function. can someone help me?

Comment: a SO question usually should have a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. What code did you try ? what would be the signature of the code you need (if you really can't figure how it should be written) ?

Answer (score 3):

> To use blockinfile on multiple files to change blocks of text ...

you might want to create templates and loop the blockinfile module.

```
- blockinfile:
    marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{ item.template }}"
    create: yes
    path: "{{ item.file }}"
    block: "{{ lookup('template', item.template) }}"
  loop: "{{ files_templates }}"
```

Comment: unfortunately does not work the dest field does not allow variables on multiple files

Comment: [Works for me](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples/tree/master/examples/example-045)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but maybe I explained myself badly.
I have 2 files tor.txt and abc.txt and I would like to use the blockinfile function for both files,
always using the same block of text.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
- name: Add same block of text in multiple files/paths
  blockinfile:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    marker: "###### {mark} Ansible Config #####"
    insertafter: EOF
    state: present
    block: |
     # Some random text comment
     Some random command1
     Some random command2

  loop:
    - {path: '/your/path/one'}
    - {path: '/your/path/two'}
```